# equation of a refracted straight line

Tags: coordinate-systems

we have got  a line $$x-y=1$$ which after refracting from $x$-axis bends at angle $\pi/6$ from normal what's eqation of that line?
what i did was that putting $y=0$ to get points on $x$-axis which comes out to be $P(1,0)$ now since it's refracted at angle $\pi/6$ hence it's angle from $x$-axis will be $\pi/2-\pi/3$ which is $\pi/3$ now writing down simply the equation 
$$(y-0)=\sqrt{3}(x-1)$$
but my answer is incorrect from what's given in textbook , where did i went possibly wrong?

Comment: $\tan(\pi/3)=\sqrt3$

Comment: corrected it but still ain't answer

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand the problem. What is the answer given?

Comment: The point on the $x$-axis should be $P(1,0)$, right?

Comment: $$(2+\sqrt{3})x-y=2+\sqrt{3}$$

Comment: From that line, it seems they mean that the ray is refracted **by** $\pi/6$ towards the normal instead of **at** an angle of $\pi/6$ from the normal. $\pi/4+\pi/6=5\pi/12$ and $\tan(5\pi/12)=2+\sqrt3$.

Comment: Mathematicians don't say "ain't."

Comment: ok i will mind using such words next time